# viewController does not update

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have 2 UIViewControllers, one starting the GameScene and the other is supposed to show the highscore, as below. The problem is that my second UIViewController does not want to show the udpated highscore. It just keeps on showing 0 all the time.
Does anyone know what the problem is? I tried using viewDidLoad as well as viewWillAppear but none of them work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = String(GameScene().highScore)
        self.view.addSubview(label)

    }
```

in the GameScene, I have declared the highScore as so:

```
var highScore = Int()
```

and used in a gameOver function as so:

```
if score > highScore {highScore = score}
```

thanks

Comment: http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/

Comment: You need to pass data from current controller to the controller you are navigating to.

Answer (score 0):

`label.text = String(GameScene().highScore)`

This piece of line suggests GameScene is a static class. Un less it is, you simply cannot access variables in such a manner.

You will need to pass data between view controllers to pass data between the scenes. You can pass data using one of three options:

1. Though performSegue()
2. performSegueWithIdentifier() and make a connection in IB
3. make a connection in IB and define an action

Comment: thank you, that helps, but now i run into the problem of how to pass the highScore value from GameScene, into a view controller, then in another view controller, i gives me the same thing 0 for score, which is not correct.

Comment: What is GameScene.swift? Is it a class that extends UIViewController or does it extend NSObject?

Comment: It extends UIViewController

Comment: Then you really shouldn't have a problem passing the values between the screens.
But this actually seems to be a problem you are facing all the time. You might want to reconsider your design. The variable is being passed around a bit too much.You could simply keep it as an app level variable using UserDefaults.

Comment: alright, I finally decided to use UserDefaults after many fails with other methods + user defaults saves the highScore, which is just what I need. Interesting though that variables do not get refreshed otherwise, when passed between viewcontrollers. Thanks a lot.